How to call Netsuite RESTlet from salesforce or any other application?
I have created RESTlet script to perform CRUD operations. I am calling that RESTlet from Postman. I have no idea of how to call the RESTlet from salesforce or other application for integration purpose? How to pass application data to RESTlet parameters(requestParams, requestBody)? Please advice.
Below is sample RESTlet script,
/**

@NApiVersion 2.1

@NScriptType Restlet
*/
define(['N/record'],
(record) => {
const get = (requestParams) => {
log.debug("Get Request Triggered",JSON.stringify(requestParams));
     var objRecord = record.load({
         type: record.Type.CUSTOMER, 
         id: requestParams.id,
         isDynamic: true,
     });

     return objRecord;
     //return "successful get request"

 }


 const put = (requestBody) => {

     log.debug("Get Request Triggered",JSON.stringify(requestBody));
     var id = record.submitFields({
         type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
         id: requestBody.customerid,
         values: {
             email: 'monika.phalle@theblueflamelabs.com'
         },
         options: {
             enableSourcing: false,
             ignoreMandatoryFields : true
         }
     });

     return{
         "status":"success",
         "message":"successfully updated the customer with id"+id
     }

 }


 const post = (requestBody) => {
     //try{

     log.debug("POST Request Triggered",JSON.stringify(requestBody));
     var customerRecord = record.create({
         type: requestBody.recordType
      });
      log.debug("customerRecord",customerRecord);

      customerRecord.setValue({fieldId:'companyname', value:requestBody.companyname});

      var cname=customerRecord.getValue({fieldId:'companyname'});
      log.debug("cname",cname);

      customerRecord.setValue({fieldId:'subsidiary', value:requestBody.subsidiary});

      var customerId=customerRecord.save();

      return JSON.stringify({'customerid':customerId,'message':'Craeted Successfully'})


 }


 const doDelete = (requestParams) => {

     record.delete({
         type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
         id: requestParams.customerId,
     });
 }

 return {get, put, post, delete: doDelete}

});



I don't know about NetSuite gurus, I'm a Salesforce guy. That restlet source code doesn't mean anything to me but if you successfully call it from Postman - can you use the code button (looks bit </>, upper right corner) and export the call as HTTP or curl - should be easy to recreate it as similar Apex code. How do you need to call it from SF? on button click? on record create/update?

I want to sync records from Salesforce to Netsuite. After create , edit and deletion of Salesforce record
